# UNITY: passing in a new datacontext each time?

Tags: linq-to-sql, dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container, datacontext

I am trying to use unity to automatically inject a datacontext on my repository using a new instance each time.., my idea is the ensure that each time a new datacontext is injected

Currently its failing on creating the repository, i think it can't resolve MyDataContext

Before creating a constructor on "the repository" (see below) to take in the DataContext on my repository everything worked but now its failing..

I currently have this setup in my unity container which i create in global.asax, i have also registered the type MyDataContext which is standard DataContext

```
        container = new UnityContainer();

        Container.RegisterType<MyDataContext, MyDataContext>()
            .RegisterType<IOfficeRepository, OfficeRepository>()
            .RegisterType<IOfficeService, OfficeService>();
```

basically i have a service that calls the repository like so

```
public class OfficeService : IOfficeService
{

    IOfficeRepository repository = null;

    public OfficeService(IOfficeRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;

        if (this.repository == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Repository cannot be null");
    }
```

here is my repository

```
public class OfficeRepository : IOfficeRepository
{
    private MyDataContext db;

    public OfficeRepository (MyDataContext dataContext)
    {
        this.db = dataContext;
    }
```

**EDIT**

I almost forgot i am doing this to create the service

```
officeService = Bootstrapper.Container.Resolve<IOfficeService>();
```

**EDIT - THE ERROR BEING GENERATED**

```
 Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "MarkSmith.IOfficeService", name = "".
 Exception message is: The current build operation (build key Build 
 Key[MarkSmith.OfficeService, null]) failed: The parameter repository could not be 
 resolved when attempting to call constructor 
 MarkSmith.OfficeService(MarkSmith.IOfficeRepository repository). (Strategy type BuildPlanStrategy, index 3)
```

**EDIT - REMOVING Constructor on repository works**

It is something to do with the datacontext because if i remove the constrcutor on the repository that takes a DataContext then all works, but of course i need it to accept a DataContext to be able to inject a "NEW" datacontext each time

```
public class OfficeRepository : IOfficeRepository
{
    private MyDataContext db new MyDataContext(); // CHANGE

    //public OfficeRepository (MyDataContext dataContext)
    //{
        //this.db = dataContext;
    //}
```

**EDIT - ACTUAL ERROR**

After digging deeper i have found this error ....

```
The type MyDataContext has multiple constructors of length 2. 
Unable to disambiguate. (Strategy type DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy, index 0)
(Strategy type BuildPlanStrategy, index 3)
```

**EDIT - TEST TO RESOLVE THE DATACONTEXT with 1 line of code**

This also fails with the same error as above - multiple constructors

```
  MyDataContext test = Bootstrapper.Container.Resolve<MyDataContext >();
```

**EDIT - ALL CONSTRUCTORS ON MY DATACONTEXT**

These were created by an exernal util but all should be well..

```
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public MyDataContext()
        : base(ConnectionString, mappingCache)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public MyDataContext(string connection)
        : base(connection, mappingCache)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public MyDataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection)
        : base(connection, mappingCache)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public MyDataContext(string connection, System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource)
        : base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public MyDataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection, System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource)
        : base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }
```

**EDIT - To demonstrate creating the DataContext in code without Unity works 100% without issue**

```
   MyDataContext tes2t = new MyDataContext ();
```

Comment: Updated question to show how i am resolving my Service using unity

Comment: What happens if you attempt to resolve a MyDataContext instance using  at various points? Everything appears to be in order, but that may give us a clue.

Comment: Also, is there a missing line or typo in the first code extract? It looks like `container` and `Container` would be different instances. You could check that you have the instance you expect by using the debugger.

Comment: I have updated the question with the error msg "The type has multiple constructors of length 2. Unable to disambiguate."

Comment: Hi GraemeF .. yep you were right... i was using 2 different Containers.. but it still fails when i have fixed it.. I am now using container across the board (notice small caps "c") - this was a typo in code on my part.

Comment: With regards to the dataContext .. i just was to pass in a new one using the NO paramter constructor as this reads my web.config for connection string

Comment: OK, so... Does `MyDataContext` have any other constructors we're not aware of?

Comment: Thanks GraemeF, yes it has a few, as i say i am only intertested in the zero param constructor

Comment: I also have created (updated question) the DataContext in code and it works. So its not a issue with teh datacontext..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure this works, but have you tried to register MyDataContext as a component rather than a type mapping?

```
container.RegisterType<MyDataContext>();
```

instead of

```
container.RegisterType<MyDataContext, MyDataContext>();
```

---

**EDIT based on new information**

The culprit seems to be that MyDataContext has more than one constructor. This is a common issue with most DI Containers, because they need to pick and use only one. If you can remove the ambiguity by constraining MyDataContext to have only one constructor, that will probably be the simplest solution.

Otherwise, you should be able to use an InjectionConstructor instance to identify the constructor when you register the repository. Let's assume you want to use a constructor that takes a connection string as an argument:

```
string connectionString =
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
var injectedConnectionString = new InjectionConstructor(connectionString);
container.RegisterType<MyDataContext>(injectedConnectionString);
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, i did try that and its the same. I have updated my question with the specific error..

Comment: Updated question also to show removing constructor works but of course i need the constructor to accept a DataContext - any ideas?

Comment: Thanks mark! excellent thank you.. going to give it a try now.. 1 sec ! thanks

Comment: Excellent! You sorted it it!!  I learn something new everyday! I took the shortcut way as i am interested in 0 params so i did this... and it seems to work

     RegisterType<MyataContext>(new InjectionConstructor());

Comment: With regards to removing the constructors, this isn't really an option due to the fact its created by an external tool and who knows one day i may need them .. :-) ... but passing in the InjectionConstructor works great

Answer (score 3):

With multiple constructors to choose from, Unity doesn't know which one to use. It will choose the one with the most arguments that can all be satisfied, but in this case there are two constructors each with two resolvable arguments.

If you don't want to couple your `MyDataContext` class to Unity and use the `InjectionConstructor` attribute as suggested by Scott (upvoted :)), you can specify the constructor that should be used at the time of registration using the fluent interface. See [Configuring Constructor, Property, and Method Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203208.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your MyDataContext constructors; but try to add the [InjectionConstructor] attribute to the one you want to use.

Comment: That should work, but will tightly couple MyDataContext to Unity.

Comment: This infact does work!!! But as pointed out by Mark its tightly coupled and also my datacontext is created by an external util so the attribute would be overwritten... I really don't fully understand why unity is having an issue, i am not interested in any constructor (i.e. constructors with 2 aprams) i am only interested in the zero param constructor and of course there is only 1... Is there an alternative ???